# User control property set in code front is null in OnPreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net

`TestPage` has a property `Items` I want to pass into my custom user control `Control`. I like the syntax of setting the property in code-front, so TestPage.aspx looks like this...

**The Page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPage" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Control.ascx" TagPrefix="custom" TagName="Control" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>

    <custom:Control ID="TestControl" Items='<%# Items %>' runat="server" />

</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind for `TestPage` has the property `Items` with a simple getter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class TestPage : Page
{
    protected List<string> Items = new List<string>() { "Hello", "world!", };
}
```

**The Control:**

My custom user control has a repeater to render the values in `Items`.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Control.ascx.cs" Inherits="Control" %>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" ItemType="System.string" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Item %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The control's code-behind exposes the public `Items` property and binds it to the `Repeater`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class Control : UserControl
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater.DataSource = Items;
        Repeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

The rendered page is empty, because `Control.Items == null` in `OnPreRender`.

If I set `TestControl.Items = Items` in `TestPage.Page_Load`, `Control.Items` is populated in `Control.OnPreRender`.

That works, but I'm pedantic. Is it possible to bind the repeater when `Items` is set in `TestPage`'s code front?

Comment: Do you call TestControl.DataBind() anywhere? The `<%# ... %>` syntax only sets the property if you invoke DataBind on the control.

Comment: @MichaelLiu that's the ticket. I'm used to thinking of data-binding only in the context of built-in controls. For some reason, didn't occur to do it in a custom control. Drop an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Items='<%# Items %>'` data-binding assignment in

```
<custom:Control ID="TestControl" Items='<%# Items %>' runat="server" />
```

will only be performed if you call the DataBind method of the control:

```
TestControl.DataBind();
```

If your page has other data-binding expressions, you can alternatively call `Page.DataBind()`, which will recursively bind all child controls.